# Google Earth Engine: only getting mean values for one point in a multi-year range

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi, landsat

I'm currently using the code below to attempt to download a mean monthly NDVI value for different zipcodes in a state, and I am looking at a period of 4 years (so I would want around ~50 mean values for each zipcode).

When I run the code below however, my csv only has each zipcode featured once, so I'm assuming that the mean NDVI value isn't calculated per month. Additionally, the systemindex column, which I would want to give me information about the date & month, has values like "0000000000000000000c_0000000000000000000c". How could I change my code?

```
var shp = table

// Load the Landsat 8 Collection 1 Tier 1 32-Day NDVI Composite
var ndvi = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_32DAY_NDVI')
              .filterDate('2015-12-01', '2020-01-31')
              .select('NDVI')
              ;


var newNDVI = ndvi.map(function(image) {
  return image.updateMask(image.select('NDVI').gt(0));
});

// Split the FeatureCollection into subsets
var subsets = shp.limit(5000, 'system:index');

// Calculate the mean NDVI for each subset of features
var ndviByFeature = subsets.map(function(subset) {
  var mean = newNDVI.mean().reduceRegions({
    collection: subset,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 30
  });
  return mean.set('date', ee.Date(ndvi.first().get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
}).flatten();

// Print the resulting table
print('Mean NDVI by feature:', ndviByFeature);

// Export the table to your Google Drive
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ndviByFeature,
  description: 'mean_ndvi_by_feature',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

`reduceRegions()` calculates the mean for each zip code. You are, however, also calculating the mean across all months with this:

```
newNDVI.mean()
```

If you want mean NDVI per zip-code per month, you can do something like this:

```
var meanNDVI = ndvi.map(function(image) {
  return image
    .updateMask(image.select('NDVI').gt(0))
    .reduceRegions({
      collection: subsets,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      scale: 30
    })
    .map(function (feature) {
      return feature.set('date', image.date().format('yyyy-MM'))
    })
}).flatten()
print(meanNDVI)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c6272afd1ef6e130d01d4db27aad32d6